# Additive monotone function $g: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $g(s) = sg(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

I'm struggling to prove the following assertion:

Let $g: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function satisfying $g(s + t) = g(s) + g(t)$ for all $s,t > 0$. Then $g$ satisfies $g(s) = sg(1)$ for all $s > 0$.

I don't really know where to start, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: For all $s>0$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 1$, you have $g(ns) = ng(s)$.

Comment: Yes first, begin with natural, then rational number, then real one using a sequence of rational number and using the first satisfied relationship and the one on rational.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Monotone_Additive_Function_is_Linear

Comment: Thank you very much all!